# Using a GD image file to create a new Imagick image

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I have a script that uses GD in PHP to create an image. I want to use Imagick to then skew this image. Right now my GD script ends like this:

```
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

I removed these last two lines and replaced them with:

```
$image = new imagick(); 
$image->readImageBlob($img);
```

but it doesn't work, it errors out with the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object'
```

I don't fully understand readImageBlob and the documentation is terrible so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just use `imagick` to begin with?

Comment: Are you sure you're even declaring the `$avcanvas` variable?

Comment: Would help significantly if we could see the whole code block.

Comment: Thanks everyone, here is a more significant chunk of the code hopefully this helps http://pastebin.com/67TgWGrt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [readImageBlob](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php) function takes a string as parameter, not a GD resource. A *blob* is the string representation of your binary data : so you need to extract those data from the GD resource.

Try to end your script this way :

```
ob_start();                   // starts output buffering
imagepng($img);               // writes image to that buffer
$blob = ob_get_clean();       // gets buffer as a string and clean it
$image = new imagick();  
$image->readImageBlob($blob);
```